# Is it possible to differentiate between IE8 and IE9 using XSL/XPATH?

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, xslt

I'm trying to determine browser version using XSL only. I'm able to determine browser type with:

```
<xsl:if test="system-property('xsl:vendor') = 'Microsoft'">
```

This test will give me the MSXSL version, but both IE8 and IE9 seem to use version 3.

```
<xsl:value-of xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" select="system-property('msxsl:version')" />
```

Is there anything else I can do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am curious how you exactly use XSLT with IE 9 that you get version 3. When I load http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/processorTest.xml with IE 9 beta (9.0.7930.16406) on Vista it shows version "6" not "3".

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**AFAIK, IE9 uses/will use MSXML6**.

You can use this by retrieving this information with:

```
system-property('msxsl:version')
```

where the prefix `msxsl:` is bound to the namespace `"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"`.

For IE x, where x <= 8 the result is <= 3.

For IE9 the result is `6`.

Comment: IE9 have dependency of Vista, and Vista comes with MSXSL 6. Others platform (say XP) can also have instaled MSXSL 3, or 4 or 6.

Comment: @Alejandro: IE always installs the version of MSXML it needs -- so no dependency on any platform.